# Combine two const arrays in a matrix with recursive C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I have searched for similar questions but I was only able to find a partial answers.

The code below is a toy example and only shows a simple template recursion. I want to generate a single configuration "matrix" from the two arrays array1 and array2. In this example I am able to recurse over a single dimension, but I would like to do it for both; e.g. use each element of array1 with each element of array2.

What is a possible solution to access a random configuration by [x][y]? Maybe an additional struct with an outer recursion?

```
#include <iostream>

const int array1 [] = {1,2,3};
const int array2 [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

template <int I, int J>
struct inner
{
    inner<I, J - 1> rest;

    int x;
    inner() : x(array1[I]-array2[J])
    {

    }
};

template <int I>
struct inner<I,0>
{
    int x;
    inner() : x(array1[I]-array2[0])
    {

    }
};

int main ()
{
    inner<3,3> test;
    std::cout << (reinterpret_cast<int*>(&test)[3]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use templates for this, or is it an academic teaser?

Comment: yes. In the concrete problem, the initialization at compile time is a must.

Comment: Neither your code not the description gives me an idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The code as posted is accessing past the end of `array1`.